# Asking engineering questions at Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Actually I am coming from an engineering background in mechanical stream, and I find most of the questions discussed here are related to IT. Will I be getting answers if I ask questions related to a mechanical background?

This will help me in learning many new topics.

Comment: Note that StackExchange isn't just StackOverflow, and SO isn't the only site that is related to technology.

Comment: What is *"mechanical stream"*? Do you mean *"mechanical systems"*?

Answer (score 11):

There is a complete site dedicated to [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

> Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals and students of engineering. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about engineering.

You can take their [tour](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help centre](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to learn if the topics match your interest.

If not there is always the full list of [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) with other sites with types of engineering:

- [reverse](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [network](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)
- [electrical](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

each site has a dedicated help center, be sure to visit those, see what type of questions are asked, learn to recognize which question do well, study their tags and tag wiki's, familiarize yourself with search etc before you ask your own question on any of these sites.